# Can there be anything between keyword 'class' and class name in c++?

Tags: c++, class

I encountered a code in c++  where class has been defined like :

```
class MACRO class_name
{
     public :

     private :

}
```

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that. I'd advise staying away from...wherever you found that.

Comment: Yep, you can do it using #define:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3563783/class-name-macro

But it smells bad :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you saw it on a Windows code, this is probably a macro which determine if you want to export or import the given class.

It's very common if you are dealing with dll-s.

So, this macro is probably something like this:

```
#ifdef  PROJECTNAME_EXPORTS

#define MACROBEFORECLASSNAME __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define MACROBEFORECLASSNAME __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
```

If you compile the dll, the PROJECTNAME_EXPORTS preprocessor definition should be defined, so the compiler will export the given class.
If you compile a project which is just using the given dll, the ...EXPORTS won't be defined, so the compiler will import the given class.

Comment: You are right, i am talking about windows, i edit the post. :)

Comment: On MSVC, there's also `__declspec(novtable)`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k13k85ky.aspx

Answer (score 8):

In standard C++11 and later, there can be attributes between `class` and the class name. It is also possible (even more likely, perhaps) that the macro expands to non-standard attribute syntax supported by the particular compiler that is being used to compile the code.