# Preprocessor macro to get the name of the current class?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

Similar to what `__FUNCTION__` does for the current function, Is there a preprocessor macro to get the name of the current class?

Comment: Look at [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666802/class-macro-in-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666802/class-macro-in-c)

Comment: What for? There may be other ways.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no such macro - sorry.

But nevertheless: `__FUNCTION__` (or `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` with gcc) should give you the name of the enclosing class - you just have to extract it.