# How do I imitate the Microsoft version of __FUNCTION__ using gcc?

Tags: c++, windows, macos, gcc, compiler-construction

When I use the `__FUNCTION__` macro/variable to print out debugging information, there seems to be a difference in what it outputs when using the Microsoft C++ compiler and gcc. For example, using the following trivial code:

```
class Foo 
{
    public:
       void Bar(int a, int b, int c)
       {
           printf ("__FUNCTION__ = %s\n", __FUNCTION__);
       }
};

int main (void)
{
    Foo MyFoo;

    MyFoo.Bar();

    return 0;
}
```

Using the Microsoft Visual C++ compiler, I get

```
__FUNCTION__ = Foo::Bar
```

whereas when compiling using gcc (in this case on the Mac), I get

```
__FUNCTION__ = Bar
```

The second example is not ideal because I quite often have several classes with, say, `Init()` and `Uninit()` methods and in a debug output trace its virtually impossible to tell which one of these has been called as the class name will be missing. Now, I know you can use the `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` in place of `__FUNCTION__` to get something like

```
__PRETTY_FUNCTION__ = void Foo::Bar(int, int, int)
```

Which is fine, but its a bit too verbose for what I need and gets a bit long for functions with a lot of parameters.

So my question is (at last), is there any way to get the output to look like simply `Foo::Bar` using gcc, as in the example above?

Comment: I'm curious as I have never needed this macro, why do you need it?  Does your compiler/test suite/memory checker not tell you the exact line of code where the problem occurs? - if its for logging then I suggest writing logs that will be identical no matter the compiler used - for then you can write pattern matching tools to analyse the logs.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the difference between __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __FUNCTION__, __func__?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4384765/whats-the-difference-between-pretty-function-function-func)

Comment: Not a duplicate -- that question has nothing to say about how to get a Microsoft-style string out of GCC.

Comment: @Steve and porkchop: I am sorry, I was too fast, though the title is not unmisleading then.

Comment: @phresnel: I've edited the title, based on the question in the last line of the body. porkchop: hope the new title represents what you actually wanted to know :-)

Comment: Btw, in case it matters `__FUNCTION__` isn't really a macro. Microsoft documents it along with its implementation-specific macros, but the clue is that it's not actually substituted by the preprocessor when you compile with `/P`. The C99 and C++11 standards don't define `__func__` as a macro (and it doesn't yield a string literal), and gcc comes right out and documents that they aren't. The reason is just that the preprocessor is too dumb to recognise a function definition.

Comment: @Steve: Thanks for that, I did struggle to find a title which conveyed what I wanted to say in the rest of the question and wasn't massively long. Yours covers it nicely!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using it for tracing, you can always use `typeid(T).name()` and just conditionally compile per platform.  Certainly not as convenient as the macro, but it could work.

Vaguely similar to [__CLASS__ macro in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666802/class-macro-in-c)

Comment: Going this route with GCC the [demangling library](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/ext_demangling.html) might come in handy.

Answer (score 2):

The function-name sanctioned by the standard is defined as follows:

```
static const char __func__[] = "function-name ";
```

Example:

```
#include <iostream>

namespace meh {
    void foobar() { std::cout << __func__ << std::endl; }
};

struct Frob {
    void foobar() { std::cout << __func__ << std::endl; }
    static void barfoo() { std::cout << __func__ << std::endl; }
};

int main () {
    std::cout << __func__ << std::endl;
    meh::foobar();
    Frob().foobar();
    Frob::barfoo();
}
```

However, output with g++:

```
main
foobar
foobar
barfoo
```

However, that is valid C++ behaviour:

> § 8.4.1, 8: The function-local predefined variable `__func__` is defined as if a definition of the form `static const char __func__[] = "function-name ";`
>   had been provided, where function-name is an implementation-defined string. It is unspecified whether such a variable has an address distinct from that of any other object in the program

I.e., you may not trust in its value. If you want to use non-portable extensions, have a look at a similar question: [What's the difference between __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __FUNCTION__, __func__?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4384765/whats-the-difference-between-pretty-function-function-func) .