# Something between __func__ and __PRETTY_FUNCTION__?

Tags: c++, gcc, macros

I work with g++ 4.8.1 and use these two macros for debugging. However, the `__func__` macro gives me only the function name, which might be misleading in the case you have many functions with the same name in different classes. The `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` macro produces the whole function signature - with return type, class name and all arguments, which can be very long.

I'd like to have something between - a macro, which will give me only class name and function name. Any way to achieve that?

Comment: Assuming you are in a non-static member function, you could use the type of `this`, `typeid` and http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/ext_demangling.html to get the class name.

Comment: The class name and function name won't always uniquely identify the function.

Comment: @KeithThompson - I can live with that, I don't need 100% precision - it's only debugging

Comment: I find `__FILE__ "(" STRINGIZE(__LINE__) "): " __func__ " - "` works excellent, _especially_ in MSVC which recognizes this syntax especially.

Comment: By the way, `__func__` is not a macro, that's why it's lowercase.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666802/is-there-a-class-macro-in-c/15775519#15775519), I created the following macro `__COMPACT_PRETTY_FUNCTION__`:

```
std::string computeMethodName(const std::string& function, const std::string& prettyFunction);

#define __COMPACT_PRETTY_FUNCTION__ computeMethodName(__FUNCTION__,__PRETTY_FUNCTION__).c_str() //c_str() is optional


std::string computeMethodName(const std::string& function, const std::string& prettyFunction) {
    size_t locFunName = prettyFunction.find(function); //If the input is a constructor, it gets the beginning of the class name, not of the method. That's why later on we have to search for the first parenthesys
    size_t begin = prettyFunction.rfind(" ",locFunName) + 1;
    size_t end = prettyFunction.find("(",locFunName + function.length()); //Adding function.length() make this faster and also allows to handle operator parenthesys!
    if (prettyFunction[end + 1] == ')')
        return (prettyFunction.substr(begin,end - begin) + "()");
    else
        return (prettyFunction.substr(begin,end - begin) + "(...)");
}
```

What it does:

- It takes `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`
- It removes return type and all arguments
- If the function has zero arguments, it appends `()`, otherwise `(...)`

Features:

- Handles namespaces, constructors and so on
- Works also with the parenthesis operator!

Limitations:

- It only works with gcc
- Created at runtime rather than compile time
- Heap allocated.
- Does not work for lambdas, [`__FUNCTION__` and `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` don't match](http://cpp.sh/5kb5)... I would almost call it a compiler bug :)

  - `__FUNCTION__` sees an `operator()`
  - `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` sees `<lambda(...)>`

Comment: Limitations: Created at runtime rather than compile time, and is heap allocated.

Comment: @MooingDuck Is there a way to avoid this, for example with `constexpr` in C++11? Can you help me with that? (In my case it is not so important because used only during debugging).

Comment: Well, if you're crafty, you could potentially add something super complicated to place the names into a compile-time _buffer_, but it'd be hard, I probably wouldn't bother.  However, I _would_ alter `computeMethodName` to use `const char(&)[N]` as much as possible to reduce the number of heap allocations.  I'll whip something up.

Comment: Yours actually seems to work for pretty complex cases too!  http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8d2dd99099c813f0  But not pathalogical cases: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6a09d229735cfc72

Comment: Made a version with zero allocations, though the method name is only valid until the next call in the same thread.  I figure that's livable.  http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/132eb50d00b4cb7f  Doesn't quite get pathalogical cases right, but pretty good.

Comment: @MooingDuck Very interesting, thanks! I also seem to understand what you mean with the threading issue :), and yes, it's livable!

Comment: @Mathias Interesting! What does `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` look like for a lambda function?

Comment: I guess a regexp would be the simplest for the general case (http://cpp.sh/4wb7p). Of course performance may suffer when solving for the general case. A constexpr solution would be nice.

Comment: @Mathias I have updated my answer in any case. I dare to call it a "compiler bug" :)

Comment: Shouldn't computeMethodName be a constexpr fucntion?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunatly, I don't think this can be done easily. I am one of those that don't understand why nobody ever proposed the implementation of a `__CLASS__` macro, that could expand to the current class, similarly to [all the macros defined by GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Standard-Predefined-Macros.html), for example.

I agree that these macros are great help in some difficult debugging situations. Probably difficult to implement.