# __PRETTY_FUNCTION__: Can a return type contain parentheses?

Tags: c++, gcc, macros

I was considering [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15775519/2436175) to reduce the output of `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`. That solution removes return type, arguments and modifiers.

I was wondering if the following modification would work in any case:

```
inline std::string methodName(const std::string& prettyFunction) {
    size_t parenthesis = prettyFunction.find("("); //Then I can use parenthesis index as end for my string
    size_t begin = prettyFunction.rfind(" ",parenthesis) + 1;
    (...)
}
```

Namely, I would like to understand if there's any chance that the return type (or anything else, in the string returned by `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`, at the left of the function name) contains an open parentheses `(`

---

I implemented the method in [a different way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29856690/2436175).

Comment: `void (*func())()` returns a function pointer. Does it break your code ?

Comment: @Quentin Yes it does :) Although that shouldn't be present in the code I will have to log

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there can be other parentheses.  Here's an example:

```
#include <iostream>

using fptr = void(*)();

fptr func() {
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';
    return nullptr;
}

int main()
{
    func();
}
```

Output using g++ -std=c++14 is:

```
void (* func())()
```

Comment: Thanks! I think this case should not be present in the code I am dealing with. If you come to think to any other case please let me know. I will in any case try to create a general version of the function.