# How to write to log the function and class name i am in ?

Tags: c++, logging, macros

I have a simple state machine, there is a class called `IState` with one function :

```
IState doSomething(int i);
```

I have many inheritors, `Astate`, `BState` ...

i want to log in which state i'm currently at, i thought maybe i could write in all my implementation of doSomething the following line :

```
writeToLog("current function is" << __function__);
```

but unfortunately it doesn't help , because all the functions named identically, is there a way to write the full function name with it's class name?

Thanks

Comment: Which compiler are you using?

Answer (score 1):

If your `writeToLog` function just expects a C string then you can do this:

```
writeToLog("current function is" __FUNCTION__);
```

Note that there is no comma (or any other operator) between `"current function is"` and `__FUNCTION__` - C and related languages automatically concatenate string literals.

Note also the use of `__FUNCTION__` rather than `__function__`.

Answer (score 1):

For g++ to get the class name you can use: [Is there a __CLASS__ macro in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666802/is-there-a-class-macro-in-c)

For function names you can always use the `__FUNCTION__` macro.

And if I remember correctly for MSVC the `__FUNCTION__` macro expands to contain the class name too.

And the mandatory links:

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Standard-Predefined-Macros.html

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The Standard's requirements of `__func__` are:

> The function-local predefined variable **func** is defined as if a definition of the form

```
static const char __func__[] = "function-name ";
```

> had been provided, where function-name is an implementation-defined string. It is unspecified whether
>   such a variable has an address distinct from that of any other object in the program.

Any other macro you may be using is non-Standard - you'll have to look to your compiler documentation or share which one you're using.