# Get the name of the class calling a function

Tags: c++, qt, debugging

## Context

I'm writting a debug class in Qt for a project and I want to know in which class I am so now I write:

```
MyClass::function1()
{
   DEBUG_IN("[MyClass] Enters function1()")
   ....do something
   DEBUG_OUT("[MyClass] Exits function1()");
}
```

**EDIT:**  `DEBUG_IN()` and `DEBUG_OUT()` are global functions. They are not part of the class MyClass

## The question

Is it possible to get the name of the class where DEBUG() is called?

(and the bame of the function where DEBUG() is called?)

so that I could just do:

```
MyClass::function1()
{
   DEBUG_IN("function1()")
   ....do something
   DEBUG_OUT("function1()");
}
```

and

```
DEBUG_IN(QString text)
{
   qDebug() << qPrintable("[")
            << qPrintable(getClassName())
            << qPrintable("] Enters ")
            << qPrintable(text);
}
```

Thx a lot

Comment: Try looking at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666802/is-there-a-class-macro-in-c. If you aren't familiar with how macro expansion works I can try to clarify that for you.

Comment: @qartar: You gave me the same answer as the 2 other propositions, however I DEBUG() is not part of MyClass (I just edited the question because it wasn't clear enough)

Comment: You can pass the expanded macro directly to the function. e.g. `DEBUG_IN(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__, ...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed there is.

```
typeid(*this).name()
```

Will give you a readable classname. It is not specified how this name is constructed so your compiler might not give the exact class name, but it should be good for debugging purposes.

As DEBUG_IN and DEBUG_OUT are free functions you need to pass the class type as an argument. A simple template should do the trick

```
template<typename CLASSNAME>
void DEBUG_IN(QString msg, CLASSNAME* that)
{
   ...  typeid(*that).name()

}
```

Comment: The problem is that it gives me only that i'm in DEBUG_IN but not the class from where DEBUG_IN is called. I just edited my question because it wasn't clear, it seems

Comment: how would you use DEBUG_IN() ? You would always have to add `this` in parameter aren't you?

Comment: I don't believe that it's required to give you a readable classname at all. You could get a mangled name, which I'm pretty sure is *mandatory* for Itanium.

Comment: @Puppy I'd be surprised if a compiler gave a name that would not allow you to discern the class.

Comment: I don't get the discussion between Puppy and Captain Giraffe

Answer (score 2):

The closest to what you want would be `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`. This includes fully qualified function name and signature.

Edit:

You should use it like this:

```
#define DEBUG_IN_PRETTY(...) DEBUG_IN(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __VA_ARGS__)
```

then call `DEBUG_IN_PRETTY` (obviously `DEBUG_IN` needs to take the extra argument). This will expand the macro at the call site.

Comment: the problem is that it gives me only that i'm in DEBUG_IN but not the class from where DEBUG_IN is called. See my Edit

Comment: Can you change the definitions of the DEBUG_* functions?

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe Yes I can. An idea? Else I could just copy paste everywhere DEBUG(typeid(*this).name(), "function1()") but I hope to be able to gain more time :)

Comment: @ochurlaud Pass this as a second argument. See my edit.

Comment: @ochurlaud: You can define another macro that passes it in.