# How to get class type in class scope with a macro without any arguments?

Tags: c++, c++11, macros, c++14

Is it possible to get the class type

```
struct A{

DEFINE_CLASS_NAME();

};
```

such that there is a type `A::Type` which is `A` again.
Restrictions the macro `DEFINE_CLASS_NAME` should not have ANY Argument.
This is a hypothetical question, if it is possible to access the type in class scope with declval and decltype somehow...

Comment: What's wrong with just using `A`? What's the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is there an injected class name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25549652/why-is-there-an-injected-class-name)

Comment: Good question. I'm seeing a lot of `invalid use of 'this' outside of a non-static member function` when trying the obvious options.

Comment: That's quite the puzzle, but I wonder what would be a practical use case... Even in generic code, you always have *some* way of getting the type of what you're handling from the outside.

Comment: Haven't tested this on all platforms yet and I am not sure about its stability but this might work: https://godbolt.org/g/XfWyiG

Comment: I don't see what's wrong with `struct A {
auto get_this() -> std::remove_pointer_t<decltype(this)>; typedef std::result_of_t<decltype(get_this)()> Type; };` but compilers reject `decltype(get_this)`.

Comment: @SimonKraemer GCC is afoul of [expr.prim.this]/2: "expression `this`… between the optional *cv-qualifer-seq* and the end… shall not appear within the declaration of a static member function."

Comment: @SimonKraemer: Clang complains (rightly) `error: 'this' cannot be used in a static member function declaration`

Comment: @Potatoswatter: Isn't that because the return type of `get_this` is not known until after the class declaration is complete?

Comment: @AndyG That's true of deduced return types (C++14 feature), not of trailing return types (C++11 feature).

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666802/is-there-a-class-macro-in-c I admit I was hoping for some boost magic

Comment: MSVC defines the ``__super`` macro which works in class scope.