# How to get the name of a class as std::string in C++?

Tags: c++, macros

I would like to be able to get the name of a class for each object as `std::string`. As easy solution would be to define a virtual function `get_name` for each class:

```
class Class1 {
   std::string get_name () { return "Class1";}
}
```

This process is potentially error-prone, because it requires to copy and paste the name of the class for every class. Is there a better way to auto-generate this member method by using MACRO's or any other trick at compile time?

[UPDATE]:

I just searched the available answers and the best options are:

```
struct Class1 {
    std::string get_name() {
        return __PRETTY_FUNCTION__;
    };

    std::string get_name2() {
        return typeid(*this).name();
    };
};
```

The results need a bit of post processing:

```
std::__cxx11::string Class1::get_name()
4Class1
```

Comment: The preprocessor doesn't know anything about classes.

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666802/is-there-a-class-macro-in-c

Comment: Depending on the compiler, there are macros you can use, `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` with gcc, `__FUNCTION__` with msvc etc.