# C++ lambda default arguments compiler misbehavior?

Tags: c++, gcc, lambda, clang, c++17

Which of the following C++ lambdas/statements are supposed to work according to the latest C++ specification?

Context in case this is relevant: [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64384924/3779655).

I tested the following code snippets with `-std=c++17` on Fedora 33 with clang 11.0.0 and gcc 10.2.1.

***Update:** Replace `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` with `__func__` for standard compliance. The same behavior can be observed.*

***Update2:** [Example](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct.def.general#:__func__) using `const char * s = __func__` as default argument to verify that it should be valid within a function scope (thanks to @BenVoigt).*

---

#### 1. LLVM `__func__` within lambda default argument

```cpp
void clang() {
  [](const char* c = __func__) {std::cout << c << std::endl;}();
}
```

**Expected behavior (CLANG):**

- Print out `clang\n` (`void clang()` for `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`)

**Observed behavior (CLANG):**

- Compiler warning: `warning: predefined identifier is only valid inside function [-Wpredefined-identifier-outside-function]`
- Print out `\n` (`top level()` for `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`)

---

#### 2. GCC ignores statements

```cpp
template <typename L>
constexpr std::string_view methodName(L l) { return l(); }
#define __METHOD_NAME__ (\
  __func__, /* needed for pointer to work */ \
  methodName([](const char* c = __func__) {return std::string_view(c);}) \
)
void gcc1() {
  std::cout << [](const char* c = __func__) { return c; }() << std::endl;  // GCC: This statement doesn't do anything
  std::cout << [](const char* c = __func__) { return c; }("gcc") << std::endl;
  std::cout << __METHOD_NAME__ << std::endl;  // GCC: This statement somehow conflicts with the statements above
}
void gcc2() {
  std::cout << __METHOD_NAME__ << std::endl;  // GCC: This statement itself works
}
```

**Expected output (GCC):**

```
gcc1
gcc
gcc1
gcc2
```

**Observed output (GCC):**

```
gcc
gcc2
```

---

#### 3. GCC Compile error

```cpp
void gcc3() {
  std::string_view s = [](const char* c = __func__) { return std::string_view(c); }();
  std::cout << s << std::endl;
}
```

**Expected behavior (GCC):** Compiles without problems.

**Observed behavior (GCC):** `error: internal compiler error: in finish_expr_stmt`

Comment: @Enrico: What do you mean by "define functions instead"?  The g++ extension for "local functions"?  A member function of a locally-defined class type?

Comment: I was referring to using a function rather than a lambda function object. But I had not understood the point of the question, which is how these `__variables__` behaves, lambdas being just a tool to condition what these variables refer too. (And probably I'm still misundertanding the question.)

Answer (score 0):

> [class.local] The local class is in the scope of the enclosing scope, and has the same access to names outside the function as does the enclosing function. [Note: A declaration in a local class cannot odr-use (6.2) a local entity from an enclosing scope. — end note]

A lambda is a local class, and as such it cannot use variables from the enclosing scope (e.g. `__func__`) other than in its capture clause.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Do you see any way to pass `__func__` (as a macro) to a `constexpr methodName()` other than [template-handling the string character by character](https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2017/06/28/compile-time-string-concatenation/) or waiting for [C++20 `std::basic_fixed_string` as template parameter](http://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/c-20-the-core-language#h1-2-string-literals-as-template-parameters) which doesn't seem to be implemented anywhere yet?

Comment: @darkdragon `__func__` is not a macro, it's a bona fide variable.

Comment: I need a _macro_ like `#define __METHOD_NAME__ methodName(__func__)` to use within my logger.

Comment: I'm not quite sure why you can't just use `__func__` or `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` as is. Why wrap it in a lambda or anything else?

Comment: If you have a problem defining a logger macro or function, ask a question about defining a logger macro or function. There is a zillion loggers out there that can print function names. Explain why their strategies don't work for you, with examples.

Comment: Because I want to have the full function including class name and namespace, but remove the clutter for return types and parameters. This should be done at compile time, therefore using `constexpr`. My `methodName()` will do further string handling using C++20 `substr()` and `find()`.

Comment: It isn't quite clear what your problem is. If you want to write a `constexpr` function that manipulates a string, write one, and pass it `__func__` or whatever as an argument. Why do you need a lambda for that?

Comment: Because function parameters are not `constexpr` and strings can't be used as template argument prior to C++20 (although no compiler implemented `std::basic_fixed_string` yet). If you find a way without lambdas, show me.

Comment: A way to do what exactly? So far I only see you trying to print a function name. This doesn't require anything special. If you want to print a transformed function name, then the transformer function can be constexpr and it will be evaluated at compile time. Do you want to make the lambda that somehow contains `__func__` a template argument, in lieu of `__func__` itself? You better show it in the code and explain why you need it in a template, as opposed to say a constexpr function, otherwise people will get really confused trying to suggest irrelevant solutions.

Comment: I linked my desired `constexpr` function as [context](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64384924/3779655). Already adding another `constexpr std::string_view` doesn't work: https://godbolt.org/z/zfr1hK (Thanks for the hint to godbolt.org!)

Comment: Why do you need to make local variables of `transform_method_name` `constexpr`? Leave them as normal variables. The function itself is `constexpr`, that should be enough.

Comment: O_o thanks for letting me know! I thought everything within a `constexpr` function needs to be `constexpr`... Is there a way to force `constexpr` evaluation from the _caller_ side (something like a constexpr cast)? I found `consteval` (C++20) for the _callee_ side, but would prefer to force it inline e.g. `cout << (constexpr)transform_method_name(__func__);`.

Comment: You can initialise a constexpr variable with the result of the call, and/or static_assert its result, as I show in th example. If the call cannot be made at compile time, the compiler will complain.

Comment: Is there a way to "inline" this like `std::cout << (constexpr auto x = transform_method_name(__func__), x) << std::endl;`?

Comment: Hmm no, don't think so, but just `<< transform_method_name(__func__)` should be OK. `constexpr auto x = ...` doesn't force anything, it just verifies that RHS is constexpr. You can verify it once and then use many times.

Comment: But I need to verify it for every `__func__` separately, I guess!? When I just used `<< transform_method_name(__func__)`, godbolt.org added all the functions like `substr()` to the assembly...

Comment: Tried to make them `transform_method_name` `static`? A non-static function still needs to be generated.