# In modern C++, what is the neatest way to refer to the "this" class?

Tags: c++, templates, this, auto, type-deduction

With template classes and template bases it becomes complicated to nominate the types, I often add private typedefs such as `Base` and `This` for use later:

```
template<typename T>
class A : public B<Something<T>> {
private:
    typedef B<Something<T>> Base;
    typedef A<T> This;

public:
    // .......
```

Q: is there a way to "get" `This` without defining it? This would seem like a very unambigous requirement, but maybe it's not.

I'm asking for C++17, but useful to know for *later* dialects as well.

In case you need a use-case, I am using `This` in a construct like the following (which is itself a workaround for something else):

```
private:
    auto somethingComplicated() const {
        return std::make_tuple(.........);
    }

    decltype(std::declval<This>().somethingComplicated()) field = somethingComplicated();
```

Comment: For `This` see [Injected-class-name - In class template](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/injected-class-name)

Comment: `using This = A<T>;` is "neater"

Comment: `using This = A;` is neater still ;)

Comment: to continue this trend: `A` is neater still. :)

Comment: your example isnt really showing the issue of "getting complicated". Actually `A` (or even `A<T>`) would be shorter and more clear than using `This`.

Comment: I think I wasn't explicit enough that I'd like a method invariant of the actual class name.

To give another example, think of a construct that you could use from within a macro invoked at class scope. The macro is even allowed to define members to this purpose.

Comment: hence what you put in the macro should work without knowing that the class is named A etc

Comment: if the macro needs the type of the class then it needs the type of the class. No magic can help with that

Comment: this is a duplicate for the question you didnt ask https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666802/is-there-a-class-macro-in-c

Comment: Unfortunately `decltype(*this)` only works inside methods. Even `auto declmethod() { return *this; }` doesn't help because you can only write `decltype(declmethod())` inside other methods. If you had an `A*` to call `declmethod` on, you could just call `decltype` on that `A*`.