# Why this __METHOD__NAME__ requires a memory copy?

Tags: c++, classname

The idea is from https://stackoverflow.com/a/15775519/1277762

I added a '\0' at end of string_view so we can use data() for printf, spdlog,  et al.

I use this macro to print function name with class name.

However, I find that the compiler is not smart enough to inline the string, but requires a memory copy to stack first:

https://godbolt.org/z/bqob37G3z

See the difference between CALL and CALLFUNC in main function.

Is it possible to tell compiler just put the string in some RO section, like const char *?

```cpp
template<std::size_t N>
consteval const std::array<char, N> __get_function_name(const char * arr)
{
    std::array<char, N>         data {};
    std::string_view            prettyFunction(arr);
    size_t                      bracket = prettyFunction.rfind("(");
    size_t                      space = prettyFunction.rfind(" ", bracket) + 1;
    size_t                      i;

    for (i = 0; i < bracket - space; i += 1) {
        data[i] = arr[space + i];
    }
    data[i] = '\0';

    return data;
}

#define __METHOD_NAME__ __get_function_name<strlen(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__)>(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__).data()
```

---

Thanks @n.m. and user17732522. I finally get a workable version:
https://godbolt.org/z/sof1j3Md4

Still not perfect as this solution needs search '(' and ' ' twice, which might increase compile time.

---

Updated: only call rfind(" ") once: https://godbolt.org/z/zYcajqaje

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <string_view>

constexpr size_t my_func_end(const char * arr)
{
    std::string_view prettyFunction(arr);
    return prettyFunction.rfind("(");
}

constexpr size_t my_func_start(const char * arr, const size_t end)
{
    std::string_view prettyFunction(arr);
    return prettyFunction.rfind(" ", end) + 1;
}


template<std::size_t S, std::size_t E>
constexpr const std::array<char, E - S + 1> my_get_function_name(const char * arr)
{
    std::array<char, E - S + 1> data {};
    size_t i;
    for ( i = 0; i < E - S; i += 1) {
        data[i] = arr[S + i];
    }
    data[i] = '\0';

    return data;
}

template<auto tofix>
struct fixme
{
   static constexpr decltype(tofix) fixed = tofix;
};

#define __METHOD_NAME_ARRAY__(x)    my_get_function_name<my_func_start(x, my_func_end(x)), my_func_end(x)>(x)
#define __METHOD_NAME__             (fixme<__METHOD_NAME_ARRAY__(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__)>::fixed.data())
```

Not sure if compiler can cache the calculation. If yes, it is good enough.

Comment: Perhaps it's just too complex. `__FUNCTION__` already expands to a string literal on its own so it should always be compiled as such.

Comment: Not answering the question: Identifiers containing double underscores or starting with an underscore followed by an upper-case letter are reserved to the compiler and standard library. They should not be used by user code, other than for their specified purpose. This affects both `__METHOD_NAME__` and `__get_function_name`. In the global scope any name starting with an underscore is also reserved.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/9rdcfP6Kb

Comment: @iBug The problem with __FUNCTION__ is that, it doesn't have the class name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler doesn't realize or take into account the specific behavior of `puts`, namely that it doesn't store the pointer it is passed and doesn't call its caller again.

The problem is that without this knowledge the compiler has to take into account the possibility that `puts` will store the pointer it is passed in e.g. a global variable, then calls its caller again, and then compares the new pointer argument with the old one stored in the global variable. These must compare unequal because they are pointers into different temporary objects, both in their lifetime. So the compiler can't reuse the same read-only static memory location as the argument to the `puts` call.

So you need to tell the compiler explicitly to use a static memory location:

```
#define METHOD_NAME get_function_name<my_strlen(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__)>(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__)

#define CALL() { static constexpr auto v = METHOD_NAME; puts(v.data()); }
```

Technically the `constexpr` on `v` is redundant with `consteval` on the function. Just `constexpr` on both would also be sufficient.

If you don't add `constexpr` on `v` you might want to add `const` though to make sure that the compiler won't need to consider the possibility that `puts` will modify the contents of the string, although it seems that GCC in your example is aware of that. (That `puts` takes a `const char*` as argument is not sufficient to establish this.)

---

You can't use `strlen` there by the way (assuming you want this to be portable to some other compiler beyond GCC that is supporting `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` in the way you are using it, e.g. Clang with libc++). That GCC is allowing it without diagnostic is not standard-conforming and it is not guaranteed to work on other compilers. `std::strlen` is not marked `constexpr` per standard. You can use `std::char_traits<char>::length` instead, which is `constexpr` since C++17.

Comment: \_\_PRETTY_FUNCTION__ is gcc specific anyway.

Comment: @n.m. clang also has it, but it doesn't allow `strlen` in a constexpr context.

Comment: @n.m. I clarified that it matters if portability to compilers with the same extension matters.

Comment: [`std::char_traits<char>::length(...)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/char_traits/length) can be used instead of `std::strlen` for portability, since it's `constexpr` after c++17. So you don't really need to write your own implementation

Comment: @Human-Compiler I was not aware of that. It is now added to the answer.

Comment: @user17732522 A c++17 version with your ideal. https://godbolt.org/z/r16v1ze4q

Requires a GCC extension; but looks like  gcc, clang, icx all support this extension.